# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted - Drupal

Tags: php, arrays, drupal

After doing Drupal updates, I am getting this error - I believe the previous developer (stupidly) edited core:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 74 bytes) in /home/readyby2/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 1408
```

I believe it has something to do with updating the views module. It occurs on Admin >> People >> Profiles

Any leads you can all give me?

I'm checking my common.inc, and here's line 1408 and surrounding:

```
function _filter_xss_split($m, $store = FALSE) {
  static $allowed_html;

  if ($store) {
    $allowed_html = array_flip($m);
    return;
  }
```

The offending line appears to be `$allowed_html = array_flip($m);`

Here's the full function:

```
function _filter_xss_split($m, $store = FALSE) {
  static $allowed_html;

  if ($store) {
    $allowed_html = array_flip($m);
    return;
  }

  $string = $m[1];

  if (substr($string, 0, 1) != '<') {
    // We matched a lone ">" character.
    return '&gt;';
  }
  elseif (strlen($string) == 1) {
    // We matched a lone "<" character.
    return '&lt;';
  }

  if (!preg_match('%^<\s*(/\s*)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([^>]*)>?|(<!--.*?-->)$%', $string, $matches)) {
    // Seriously malformed.
    return '';
  }

  $slash = trim($matches[1]);
  $elem = &$matches[2];
  $attrlist = &$matches[3];
  $comment = &$matches[4];

  if ($comment) {
    $elem = '!--';
  }

  if (!isset($allowed_html[strtolower($elem)])) {
    // Disallowed HTML element.
    return '';
  }

  if ($comment) {
    return $comment;
  }

  if ($slash != '') {
    return "</$elem>";
  }

  // Is there a closing XHTML slash at the end of the attributes?
  $attrlist = preg_replace('%(\s?)/\s*$%', '\1', $attrlist, -1, $count);
  $xhtml_slash = $count ? ' /' : '';

  // Clean up attributes.
  $attr2 = implode(' ', _filter_xss_attributes($attrlist));
  $attr2 = preg_replace('/[<>]/', '', $attr2);
  $attr2 = strlen($attr2) ? ' ' . $attr2 : '';

  return "<$elem$attr2$xhtml_slash>";
}
```

Comment: I don't see any memory leak in given code. If you are sure that there's something wrong to Drupal framework itself, backup your project and reinstall it. By the way, don't parse html with regex.

Comment: comment out `static $allowed_html` and your problem will probably go away, the static variable might just be holding too much information

Comment: It is only when trying to run a custom link that the client setup.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs as soon as your memory is over - this can happen anywhere in your code and does not necessary belong to the script and line number you get displayed in the error message.

Your php needs more memory in php.ini or you check your scripts for unneccessary memory usage (often to large or to many in-memory-database-records).

EDIT: the code you posted was not (stupidly) changed by a developer - it is still the original drupal code.